# How to compare couples of items within an ArrayList using for-each loop?

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a vector of object and I need to compare them 1-by-1. That is:

```
for (Object o1 : list) {
    for (Object o2 : list) {
    //Do something with o1 and o2
    }
}
```

Anyway using this approach I will compare any couple twice!
Using a "C" style approach, I would have done this:

```
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
    //Do something with list[i] and list[j]
    }
}
```

where n is the length of the list.

Is there a way to do this using for-each loop?

**Addition**

The usage of a for-each loop is not mandatory. Anyway, I'm concerned with performances issues. Does the for-each loop is faster than a simple for accessing index directly or not?

Comment: Why don't you want to use `for` loops ? They behave the same as in C.

Comment: Yes use two variables or use next index

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is explicitly clear what your intent is with the C-like for loops - loop over every pair exactly once, so that the same pair with reversed members, e.g. (a, b) and (b, a) doesn't get processed again.  That is what I would recommend; it works in Java just as well.

However, if you absolutely have to have the enhanced `for` loop, you can have the inner for loop operate over a sublist, with [`List`'s `subList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-), starting with the next element.

```
for (Object o1 : list) {
    List<Object> subList = list.subList(list.indexOf(o1) + 1, list.size());
    for (Object o2 : subList) {
         //Do something with o1 and o2
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The usage of a for-each loop is not mandatory. Anyway, I'm concerned with performances issues. Does the for-each loop is faster than a simple for accessing index directly or not?

Comment: The for-each loop creates an `Iterator` behind the scenes, using it to supply the loop with values.  It may be slightly less fast than index-based standard for loops, but for just about all applications I wouldn't worry about the performance difference.

Comment: Very nice solution! Have not thought about subList, but performance is lost here. Still +1 upvote!

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `list` is declared as `List<Whatever>`, you may achieve this behavior properly by using [`ListIterator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html) rather than for-each loops:

```
ListIterator<Whatever> iteratorI = list.listIterator();
if (iteratorI.hasNext()) {
    for (Whatever whateverI = iteratorI.next(); iteratorI.hasNext(); whateverI = iteratorI.next()) {
        ListIterator<Whatever> iteratorJ = list.listIterator(iteratorI.nextIndex());
        for (Whatever whateverJ = iteratorJ.next(); iteratorj.hasNext(); whateverJ = iteratorJ.next()) {
            //do the comparison here...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach since you are miming the index approach with iterators. Anyway, is this slower than direct access with index?

Comment: In Java 8 HotSpot, using `ListIterator` is optimized for LinkedList when initialized with an index, while for implementations like `ArrayList` provides direct access to the array element through index. Still, I haven't measured the times, this is based on reading source code.

Comment: This isn't going to work. There's no `list.listIterator(Object)` method in `ArrayList`, so it won't even compile. Even if it did, you're invoking `iteratorI.next()` twice in each iteration of the outer `for`, making whateverI skip half the elements in the list.

Comment: @ErickG.Hagstrom typo, it was `nextIndex`, not `next()`. Fixed

Answer (score 3):

The enhanced for loop is not appropriate in all situations. If you avoid using an index, just to use `indexOf` in the loop, your code will be less efficient (`indexOf` is a linear search) and non-idiomatic.

In my opinion, the best answer is to use the explicit indices.

```
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        // do something with list.get(i) and list.get(j)
    }
}
```

One situation where you should avoid using `get` is if the `List` is a `LinkedList`, because `get` for a `LinkedList` is not a constant time operation. In this case I would do

```
List<Object> copy = new ArrayList<>(linkedList);
for (i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    for (j=i+1; j<n; j++) {
        // do something with copy.get(i) and copy.get(j)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The comments suggest you do it c-style or track an explicit index. Those are good suggestions. But if you insist on doing it with the new style for loop, there is a way:

```
for (Object o1 : list ) {
    final int o1Index = list.indexOf(o1);
    final int listSize = list.size();
    for (Object o2 : list.subList(o1Index + 1, listSize)) {
    //Do something with o1 and o2
    }
}
```

The idea is that any o2 that comes before o1 in the list has already been processed, and you don't need to process o1 against itself. So you get a sublist consisting only of the elements following o1 and draw o2 from that sublist.

That will fail if any elements appear more than once in the list.

I've broken out `o1Index` and `listSize` for clarity, but in practice you'd probably in-line them.

Another option is to copy the original list and, before starting the inner loop, remove the front element each time. This properly accounts for duplicate elements, but takes more space.

```
final List<Object> newList = new ArrayList<>(list);
for (Object o1 : list) {
    newList.remove(0);
    for (Object o2 : newList) {
        // Do something
    }
}
```

Comment: I appreciate a lot your solutions. What about performances (speed of execution, not space allocated)?

Comment: The second one is much worse than the c-style for loop. It's the copying of the list and removal of elements that adds execution time. The `sublist` idea is probably equivalent to the c-style for loop since it just returns a view of the list, not an entirely new list. I haven't benchmarked either, though, so can't make any hard claims.

Answer (score 2):

You want performance?
Here you go!

> The usage of a for-each loop is not mandatory

```
int s = list.size();

for(int i = 0; i < s-1; i++){
   for(int n = i+1; n< s;n++){
      if(list.get(i).equals(list.get(n))){
        System.out.println("Duplicate");
      }
   }
}
```

You will never compare a combination twice.

Also to fully answer you question:
foreach does require more resources and reduces performance

To achieve the same result with foreach statement you'd create very much heap and slow the application down, also more instructions are processed by the CPU so you don't just loose memory but computing performance too.
Also try avoiding to call the size() method more than one time hence your list is not modified within this procedure. This also reduces CPU usage, but requires a very little bit more RAM (int s).

So your "C" style approach is almost optimal.

For ease i used java api calls, it also should be a ease to usw this example on your target framework.

EDIT: Improve performance even more by saving the list's size to reduce method calls.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific case, comparison is just an operation of an infinity of other operations, other non commutative operations have a meaning for all combinations (this is just an example).

So there is no enhanced loop for such case.

Comment: in my case, compare o1 with o2 will give the same answer as comparing o2 with o1 (commutative)

Comment: Enhanced loop is one more operation, if for every specific need we add an operation, then this breaks orthogonality.